# Concatenate Two RNN States in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning

I am trying to concatenate two LSTM states together in tensor flow. Previously, this had been done with `tf.concat`, but this isn't working for me because I need to compute logits on the resulting state, and I am unable to iterate through the resulting state since the `'Tensor' object is not iterable`.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
outputs, fstate = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm, inputs=rnn_inputs,
                                      sequence_length=lengths, 
                                      dtype=tf.float32, time_major=False)
outputs2, fstate2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm2, inputs=rnn_inputs2,
                                      sequence_length=lengths2, 
                                      dtype=tf.float32, time_major=False)

newRnnState = tf.concat([fstate, fstate2], 1)
logits = tf.matmul(tf.concat([f.h for f in newRnnState], 1), output_layer[0]) + output_bias[0]
```

This returns an error: `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.`

Is there any way to do this so that I can concatenate two RNN states together and use them like this?

Thanks

Comment: The thing is that newRnnState is a tensor and not an array, that's why you have this error. According to what you want to do, you can try this:
logits = tf.matmul(tf.concat([fstate.h, fstate2.h], 1), output_layer[0]) + output_bias[0]

Comment: @AnthonyD'amato this doesn't work because fstate is a LSTMStateTuple. However, if I do this instead `logits[0] = tf.matmul(tf.concat([fstate[0].h, fstate2[0].h], 1), output_layer[0]) + output_bias[0]`, it succeeds in the concatenation but later on complains that the output shape is not right. The shape is `(9, 512)`, when it should be `(9, 256)` since each LSTM cell has size 256. Thus, it can't do the multiplication with `output_layer[0]`, since that has a size of `(256, output)`. I don't think the right solution is to change `output_layer` size, or is it?

Comment: Ha yes sorry I forgot it was a tuple, you're right. But since each LSTM has a 256 cell size, then if you concatenate along the axis 1 both outputs, you will get 512. I'd say you have to change your output_layer size to (cell_size*2, output)

Comment: Ok, thanks! If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what we said in the comments, you should set the size of the output layer to `(2*cell_size, output_size)` since you are concatenating 2 states of cell_size size along the axis 1. Then you can use:
`tf.matmul(tf.concat([fstate[0].h, fstate2[0].h], 1), output_layer[0]) + output_bias[0]`